# Preprocessor on C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I added this in my code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG_MODE
    printf("i=%d\n",i);
    fflush(stdout);
#endif
```

and my question is, if I'm not in `DEBUG_MODE` what the compiler does when compiling this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler will do nothing, because there will be nothing there when DEBUG_MODE is not defined.

Comment: Thanks, That's what I thought

Answer (score 2):

`#ifdef` and `#endif` control conditional compilation.  This happens during an initial pass over the program, making dumb textual substitutions before the compiler even begins to consider the file to contain C code specifically.  In this case, without the symbol defined only whitespace is left.  The text is never even lexed into C tokens if the preprocessor define tested for isn't defined at that point.

You can see this for yourself: just invoke your compiler with whatever flag it uses to stop after preprocessing - e.g. `gcc -E x.cc` - and at that point in the output there will just be an empty line or two.  This is also a very important technique for understanding macros, and a good thing to do when you just can't guess why some program's not working the way you expect - the compiler says some class or function doesn't exist and you've included its header - look at the preprocessed output to know what your compiler is really dealing with.

Comment: The input is converted into a token stream, even the part that is not compiled.  See ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §5.1.1.2 Translation Phases, where phase 3 is 'The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens' and phase 4 is 'Preprocessing directives are executed'.  Preprocessing logically occurs after the source file is analyzed into preprocessing tokens.  The net result is much the same, though.

Answer (score 1):

if `DEBUG_MODE` is not defined, the code under it will not be compiled.